# KendoUi CheckBox

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

I was wondering if there is a way for me to create a "kendo" check box? I know there isn't a widget, but maybe there is a class I can apply like what I did for a textbox [as suggested here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/general-discussions/why-is-there-no-simple-input-widget.aspx) or maybe scale the check box to be bigger like what I did here, (for some reason it is not working on my desktop browser but is working fine for my mobile browser)

```
input[type=Checkbox]
{
    /* Double-sized Checkboxes */
    -ms-transform: scale(2.5,2.5); /* IE */
    -moz-transform: scale(2.5,2.5); /* FF */
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.5,2.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: scale(2.5); /* Opera */
    margin-top: 3%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    vertical-align:3%;

}
```

I know there are check and radio, but that is for the [mobile framework](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/forms/checkboxes.html), and I am using the regular web framework.

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo UI styling for the checkbox relies on the mobile stylesheets, so include them if you can - otherwise this is not possible using the web framework alone to my knowledge.